Android Studio "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_35 has terminated." issue
I installed android studio and I wanted to emulate a virtual android device and every time I try, it gives the error:

The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_35 has terminated.

I checked the idea.log file and it gives me the error:

INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API 35 - [11964:13944:20241024,132358.755:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.2.10.db\attachments\6b9963a6-5e96-4b76-bfd2-e09bf2051ff9: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)

My emu-crash-35.2.10.db folder is empty for some reason and I can't find a solution. Can you give me the solution or some advice to solve this problem?
I tried reinstalling the software but it did not help.
